# cannot resolve symbol ValueState

Tags: flink-streaming

I'm trying to use flink-streaming state backend, following this guide: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming/state.html, but I get the error: ***Cannot Resolve Symbol 'ValueState'***.

After looking a bit, I realise that **ValueState** is not in my dependencies. Instead, only **OperatorState** is in org.apache.flink.api.common.state (flink-core).

However, if I look on Github, I see ValueState in that package: https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/state

I'm guessing I either don't have the right version of flink to use the StateBackend the way the guide shows it, or maybe I have the right version but the ValueState has been moved to another maven dependency.

Below is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>flink-streaming</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>flink-streaming</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!--<flink.version>0.10.2</flink.version>-->
    <flink.version>0.10.2</flink.version>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    <scala.dependency.version>2.11</scala.dependency.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-scala_${scala.dependency.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.dependency.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_${scala.dependency.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArgs>
                    <jvmArg>-Xms64m</jvmArg>
                    <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
                </jvmArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

And here is my code:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RichFlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;


public class CountWindowAverage extends RichFlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Long,Long>, Tuple2<Long,Long>> {
    private transient ValueState<Tuple2<Long,Long>> sum;

    @Override
    public void flatMap(Tuple2<Long,Long> input, Collector<Tuple2<Long,Long>> out) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Laurent.

Answer (score 0):

You're right Flink version `0.10.x` did not yet have `ValueState`. If you switch to at least version `1.0.0` you should be all right.

Comment: I find knowing which version to use quite difficult in Flink. The official documentation and most tutorials never tell anything about the required dependencies, so you have to find an example online, which is often outdated...

Comment: There is this section in the doc: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/common/index.html#linking-with-flink For using other libraries, such as the CEP library or Flink ML they also provide the maven coordinates at the beginning of their subsection in the doc. Note that you can switch to the "Scala" tab to get info about Scala rather than Java.